# Problema da Agulha de Buffon: simulação simples

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer em python um código para simular o Problema da Agulha de Buffon. Estou tentando fazer algo extremamente simples. Simular um sorteio da distância X do centro da agulha à linha mais próxima e de  $\theta$ pertencente ao intervalo $(0, \pi/2)$  e realizar o teste verificando se $X<(L/2)cos(theta)$, se isso ocorrer acumulamos +1.

```
import random
import math
N = int(input())
d = 5
l = 3 # We have to set l that satisfy l<=d.
i = 0
S = 0
while i < N:
      X = random.uniform(5/2, 5)
      theta = random.uniform(0,math.pi/2)
      r =  l / 2 *math.cos(theta)
      if  X < r:
          i += 1
          S += 1
print(2 * l * N / (S * d))
```

o codigo está me retornando 1.2 sempre

Answer (score -1):

Claro que aparecerá sempre o valor 1.2 para o print: todos os argumentos são sempre os mesmos!

Note que `i == S` e a condição de saída é `i == N == S`

Logo no final sempre teremos `2 * l * N / (S * d) = 2*3*N/(N*5) = 6/5 = 1.2`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).